# Implementing Sieve of Eratosthenes using Linked List in C (Segmentation Fault error)

Tags: c, linked-list, bit-manipulation

I'm attempting to implement the Sieve algorithm in C for a class. I'm not asking for this assignment to be done for me. I've got my functions written out already, but am currently getting a Segmentation Fault error. I'm not 100% sure what that is. Here is my code so far, can anyone see where this error comes from?

```
#define EXTERN

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "header.h"

void clearAll() {
    int i, j;
    seg *p;
    p = head;
    for(i = 0; i < NSegs; i++) {
            p = p -> next;
            for(j = 0; j < 256; j++) {
                    p -> bits[j] = 0;
            }
    }
}
int setBit(int n) {
   int segment, index, hold, pos, i;
   seg *p;
   p = head;

   segment = n/256;
   hold = n;
   while(hold > 65) {
        hold = hold - 65;
        index++;
   }
   pos = (hold - 1)/2;

   for(i = 0; i < segment; i++) {
        p = p -> next;
        p->bits[index] = p->bits[index] | (1 << pos);
   }
}

    int testBitIs0(int n) {
   int segment, index, hold, pos, i, r;
   seg *p;
   p = head;
   segment = n/256;
   hold = n;
   while(hold > 65) {
        hold = hold - 65;
        index++;
   }
   pos = (hold - 1)/2;
   printf("%d, %d, %d ", segment, index, pos);
   for(i = 0; i < segment; i++) {
         p = p -> next;
        r = p->bits[index] & (1 << pos);
    }
}

void sieveOfE( int N )
{
   int i, j, k;


   k = 1;   // Start with 2 to find all primes

   while ( k <= N )
   {
        for ( i = k; i <= N; i++){
          if(i % 2 == 0) {
                break;
           }
          if ( testBitIs0(i) ){
              break;
          }
        }

        for ( j = 2*i; j <= N; j = j + i ){
          setBit(j);
         }
         k = i+1;
    } 
 }

int countPrimes(int n){
    int count, i;
    count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
       if(testBitIs0(i) ){
            count++;
       }
    }
    return count;
}

int printPrimes(int n){
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if(testBitIs0(i) ){
                printf("%d ", i);
           }
        }
        printf("\n\n");

}
```

The Linked List has already been properly initialized in the main and header files. The initialization came from a skeleton file and should not be edited. But each linked list node contains a bit array and a pointer to the next node.

Comment: A segmentation fault is one of the possible failures when you try to read from/write to a pointer that has not been initialized (it does not point to allocated memory). So look for that (I am not going to debug it for you).

Comment: In a related note: separate your concerns. Create the code for the linked list and check that it works. After that, implement the sieve on top of it. That way it is easier for you to check where the error is and you can post an http://sscce.org , which would make helping you easier (and more likely).

Comment: There are enough problems with this code that it's hard to pin down where precisely the problem is.  In no particular order... You seem to be trying to iterate over a linked list in (for example) setBit() but you aren't allocating any memory for the items in the linked list.  You have code which tries to iterate over the items in the linked list but assumes there are exactly NSegs in the linked list (this is very weird since if you knew how long it would need to be you should just use an array).

Comment: Also, you separate the declarations of your variables from their initialisation (for example the declaration of p and the assignment of head to it - not a bug bit very strange usage).   To identify the problem, either run your code under a debugger (learn to use it!) or use assert atatements to verify your assumptions (for example that the subscript "index" is less than the size of the array "bits" or that the pointer you are about to de-reference is in fact not NULL).

Comment: A powerful technique for solving problems with code in general is to take your buggy program, and (intelligently) remove half of it.   See if the remaining half still has a bug.   If yes, try again.   If no, perhaps you can learn about the nature of your bug by checking the code which made the bug go away when you removed it.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally forgot to mention. The Linked List has already been initialized and properly set up in skeleton code that I've received. It's contained in the header and main files!

Comment: My most general advice for you is to read more, and high-quality, code.   Learn from how other people's programs work.  Think of the analogy with creative writing - you should not assume you can write good text if you have never read good text ("text" not "English" since I don't know what your native language is).

Comment: We cannot answer because we do not know anything about: seg, head, Nsegs, next, bits. You would have to post the other files.

Comment: Using a linked list for the sieve of Eratosthenes is inefficient.  Better use a bit array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Give a programmer a fix for a segfault and you'll feed him for a day.
Teach a programmer to use a debugger and he'll feed himself for a lifetime.*

If you run your program under a debugger, it will trap the segfault crash at the line of code which caused it and you can examine the call stack.  If you use the [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb) debugger, the `bt` or `backtrace` command will display your stack.

[Here is a GDB turorial](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/).

As pointed out in the comments, segfault generally occurs when you try to dereference an invalid pointer, be it uninitialized, corrupted or wrong for any number of reasons.

Comment: I've gotten the problem down to my clearAll() function. It's the line that reads `p->bits[j] = 0;`. Would you happen to know how to clear the array properly?

Comment: @Xonal - `p` is a pointer, so almost certainly it is p that is incorrect here.  Check with `print p` in gdb.  Looking at your loop at that point in your code to walk the list, you should check to see if p is not NULL before dereferencing it.  You could change your for statement to something like `for (p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next) {`